# PySide: QStyledItemDelegate button's stylesheet Issue

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm using a QStyledItemDelegate to set a custom Button  on a model in a tableView. I set a styleSheet to the button with  a blue background-color and red background-color when the button will be pressed.

The tableview with the button and its blue background shows correctly, but when I press the button, the button's stylesheet doesn't works, its background color doesn't change to red color.

**Window with blue buttons:**

[image]

**Expected behaivor: when a button is pressed its Background should change to red**

[image]

This is my code:

```py
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class DelegateButton(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._mybtn = None

        self._rfbutton = QPushButton()
        self._rfbutton.setStyleSheet(''' QPushButton{
                                                    background-color: blue;
                                                    border:1px solid blue;
                                                    }

                                         QPushButton:pressed{
                                                    background-color: red;
                                                    border:1px solid red;
                                                    }
                                    ''')
        
        
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return None


    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        self._mybtn = QStyleOptionButton()
        
        
        top_span_height = (option.rect.height() - 24)/2
        pos_x = 8 + option.rect.x()
        pos_y = option.rect.y() + top_span_height

        self._mybtn.rect = QRect(pos_x, pos_y, 24, 24)
        self._mybtn.state = QStyle.State_Enabled


        self._rfbutton.style().drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButton, self._mybtn, painter, self._rfbutton)
        


    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if self._mybtn.rect.contains(event.x(), event.y()):
                self._mybtn.state = QStyle.State_Sunken | QStyle.State_Enabled
            return False

        return False



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    rows = 5
    cols = 2

    model = QStandardItemModel(rows, cols)
    tableView = QTableView()
    tableView.setWindowTitle("Delegate Issue")
    tableView.setModel(model)

    delegate = DelegateButton()

    tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate)
    tableView.setColumnWidth(0, 200)
    tableView.setColumnWidth(1, 200)
    tableView.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(32)
    tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

 
    for row in range(rows):
        index = model.index(row, 1, QModelIndex())
        model.setData(index, 1)

    tableView.show()
    tableView.resize(450,300)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Since you're just drawing a rectangle, there's really no point in trying to use a "ghost" button for that, since you can just use [`drawRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawRect-2). The problem, though, is somewhere else: `editorEvent` gets events for **all** indexes for which the delegate is set, so your code won't make a lot of sense anyway. So, what are you trying to achieve? Note that a simple button press to switch color may not be a good idea: what if the user clicked the item by mistake? Do you need a checked/toggleable state? And do you need to read that state afterwards?

Comment: That's exactly what i want to do,   just change background color when button is pressed.  What button does, what user achieve when clicks, the event and index manage doesn't matter. I don't need  checked/toggleable state. The code posted is focused in the button's  background color behaivor, everything else is left over.

Comment: So, the user just clicks *any* index and *all* buttons irreversibly change color? That seems just strange. What if the user wrongly clicks on any of those items by mistake, for instance while trying to get back focus on the window, or because they wanted to click on the other column and missed the right spot, or even just because they're trying to understand how the UI works? Again, can you clarify what is your actual, final purpose of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Just one button at a time, Forget all the buttons and focus just in one.   if one button is clicked then  that button change  background color. Thats all. If the user click on other colum or other window's space the button's background color restore to blue. Is intended that when a button whatever it be, is clicked, that clicked button will chage their background color. if i released it or click on other space the button restore to original background color.

Comment: I believe you're making a wrong assumption. Item delegates are set for the whole view or for specific columns or rows, but they are "abstract" objects that are used for **any** indexes they are set for. They are not widgets, they are objects that are used to manage undefined items in a view. For instance, you've set the delegate for column 1, meaning that the delegate will be used for evert item in that column. There is no "just one button", there are **all** buttons for **all** items in column 1. Almost all functions of a delegate are called indiscriminately depending on various aspects: ->

Comment: -> `editorEvent`, `paint`, etc. are called at different moments, with their own *index* argument, and the delegate must use that index as a temporary reference to do what the function requires: `paint()` could be called even after clicking on *another index*. This means that, assuming you really only need this for appearance reasons, you need to keep some reference to the "clicked" index. Now, from what you're describing, I'm under the impression that you're asking the wrong question: do you want the "button" to change color only when the item is *selected*? Also, your phrase is confusing: ->

Comment: > "if i released it or click on other space": this doesn't make sense. If you click elsewhere, it means that you already released the mouse button. What if the user drags the mouse while the button is pressed? And what about keyboard navigation? Sorry, but it seems clear that you're having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you also are very confused about some important aspects about UI interaction and the purpose of item delegates.

Comment: I've edited the post  and change the image what is intended to achieve when  a button is clicked, (my mistake, I upload a wrong image). The question is still simple  if a press a blue rectangle then want change color to red of that pressed rectangle. Thanks for you answers tough

Comment: The question might seem simple to you, but it's not, and it's clear that you've not understood what I tried to explain above (it might be my fault, though). Your assumption about "clicking" is too broad, and what I pointed out in my very last comment is exactly the issue here: first of all, a "click" can mean different things (and it could refer to *many* mouse events, including press, move-while-pressed, and release after that); this results in **a lot** of different behaviors in an item view. Sorry, it's clear that we don't understand ourselves, so I'll stop here and leave to anybody else ->

Comment: -> who hopefully might be able to better explain you what still confuses you, as you're basing your question on very simplistic assumptions, but there are many aspects that you're still misunderstanding about the purpose/behavior of item delegates (and the model/view architecture) and basic UI interaction.

Answer (score 1):

As is intended to just change the background color  when the "button" is pressed as described in the stylesheet. I found out the reason it didn't change:

The code starts with `self._mybtn.state` set as `QStyle.State_Enabled` and buttons are painted blue as describe the stylesheet, when any mouse button is pressed in the "button" area, in the EvenEditor the MousePressed event changes the state to `QStyle.State_Sunken | QStyle.State_Enabled` , but when the paint function  is called again and draws the items, the `self._mybtn.state` is set to be enable, so  it changes instantly the state ending up with button colored blue.

I declare a `self._is_pressed` variable where `QEvent.MouseButtonPress` will store the position of the cursor when a button is pressed in the button's area. And in paint function,  before it draws items, I evaluate if the `self._is_pressed` have stored the position, if it do, I evaluated the position is cointained inside the buttons area, so set the state to `QStyle.State_Sunken | QStyle.State_Enabled` and the stylesheet now can be applied and color red the button.
Otherwise the state is set to `QStyle.State_Enabled`

**Background to red:**

[image]

The code ends up:

```py
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class DelegateButton(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._mybtn = None
        self._is_pressed = None

        self._rfbutton = QPushButton()
        self._rfbutton.setStyleSheet(''' QPushButton{
                                                    background-color: blue;
                                                    border:1px solid blue;
                                                    }

                                         QPushButton:pressed{
                                                    background-color: red;
                                                    border:1px solid red;
                                                    }
                                    ''')
        
        
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return None


    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        self._mybtn = QStyleOptionButton()
        
        
        top_span_height = (option.rect.height() - 24)/2
        pos_x = 8 + option.rect.x()
        pos_y = option.rect.y() + top_span_height

        self._mybtn.rect = QRect(pos_x, pos_y, 24, 24)

        
        
        if self._is_pressed and self._mybtn.rect.contains(self._is_pressed):
            self._mybtn.state = QStyle.State_Enabled | QStyle.State_Sunken
        else:
            self._mybtn.state = QStyle.State_Enabled


        self._rfbutton.style().drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButton, self._mybtn, painter, self._rfbutton)
        




    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if self._mybtn.rect.contains(event.x(), event.y()):

                self._is_pressed = QPoint(event.x(), event.y())

                
            return True

        return False



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    rows = 5
    cols = 2

    model = QStandardItemModel(rows, cols)
    tableView = QTableView()
    tableView.setWindowTitle("Delegate Issue")
    tableView.setModel(model)

    delegate = DelegateButton()

    tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate)
    tableView.setColumnWidth(0, 200)
    tableView.setColumnWidth(1, 200)
    tableView.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(32)
    tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

 
    for row in range(rows):
        index = model.index(row, 1, QModelIndex())
        model.setData(index, 1)

    tableView.show()
    tableView.resize(450,300)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The index could be used to achive the same result but i rather opted to use the position.

in the paint function:

```py
if self._is_pressed and self._is_pressed == (index.row(), index.column()):
   self._mybtn.state = QStyle.State_Enabled | QStyle.State_Sunken
else:
    self._mybtn.state = QStyle.State_Enabled
```

in eventEditor:

```py
if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
    if self._mybtn.rect.contains(event.x(), event.y()):
      self._is_pressed = (index.row(), index.column())
    return True
```

if it is wanted to restore to blue the background after the button is released then the `QEvent.MouseButtonRelease` must be implemented.

**Blue Background after release button:**
[image]

```py
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class DelegateButton(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._mybtn = None
        self._is_pressed = None

        self._rfbutton = QPushButton()
        self._rfbutton.setStyleSheet(''' QPushButton{
                                                    background-color: blue;
                                                    border:1px solid blue;
                                                    }

                                         QPushButton:pressed{
                                                    background-color: red;
                                                    border:1px solid red;
                                                    }
                                    ''')
        
        
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return None


    def paint(self, painter, option, index):

        self._mybtn = QStyleOptionButton()
        
        
        top_span_height = (option.rect.height() - 24)/2
        pos_x = 8 + option.rect.x()
        pos_y = option.rect.y() + top_span_height

        self._mybtn.rect = QRect(pos_x, pos_y, 24, 24)


        if self._is_pressed and self._mybtn.rect.contains(self._is_pressed):
            self._mybtn.state = QStyle.State_Enabled | QStyle.State_Sunken
        else:
            self._mybtn.state = QStyle.State_Enabled | QStyle.State_Raised


        self._rfbutton.style().drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButton, self._mybtn, painter, self._rfbutton)
        


    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if self._mybtn.rect.contains(event.x(), event.y()):

                self._is_pressed = QPoint(event.x(), event.y())
            return True
        
        
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            if self._mybtn.rect.contains(event.x(), event.y()):
                self._is_pressed = None
            return True
        

        return False
```

I hope this help to anyone in aplying styles when drawing styled delegates.

Comment: Sorry, but this approach still has the same problems as above. One of them is that the painting doesn't properly update the "button" if you just keep clicking the same column (instead of alternating between them): you have to click twice to get the expected result. Then, if you remove the mouse release and try to resize the first column or any row before or including the clicked item, you'll see that the button changes state depending on its position.

Comment: Yes, there are still issues like your mention , but that are issues can be solved recalculating the points and implemented the adequate events, one can handle it according to their needs, what are you pointing out are functionalities topics, and this question was about apareance. Why when i press the button the background didn't change.

Comment: The appearance *does* depend on those functionalities, that's how delegates work.

Answer (score 1):

A fundamental aspect that **must** be kept in mind is that delegate are abstract entities that do *not* represent a specific index in the model. They are used by the view to provide proper user interaction and item display depending on the indexes those delegates are set for.

This means that the delegate functions are called indistinctly and at very different moments depending on their purpose, and there could be no "persistent" reference to a specific index, since the view could call those functions on its own and completely out of our control.

Specifying coordinates for a *unique* "button" is wrong, as the paint function can be called for other items for other reasons: for instance, when the user hovers another index, or minimizes and restores the window.

The **only** viable solution (as long as you are *actually* and *exclusively* interested in appearance) is to keep a reference to the pressed buttons, possibly by using the index they refer to.

Note that while using a "ghost button" to use the QStyle functions might be a possibility, that is completely pointless if you are only drawing a simple rectangle: just use the basic [`drawRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawRect-2) function of QPainter.

```
class DelegateButton(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._pressed_rows = set()

    def _buttonRect(self, optionRect):
        return QRect(
            optionRect.x() + 8, 
            optionRect.y() + (optionRect.height() - 24) // 2, 
            24, 24
        )
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.row() in self._pressed_rows:
            color = QColor('red')
        else:
            color = QColor('blue')
        painter.save()
        painter.setPen(color)
        painter.setBrush(color)
        painter.drawRect(self._buttonRect(option.rect))
        painter.restore()

    def createEditor(self, *args):
        return

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        if event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress:
            if self._buttonRect(option.rect).contains(event.pos()):
                self._pressed_rows.add(index.row())
            else:
                self._pressed_rows.discard(index.row())
            return True
        # comment the following block to make the pressed state persistent
        elif event.type() == event.MouseButtonRelease:
            self._pressed_rows.discard(index.row())
            return True
        return super().editorEvent(event, model, option, index)
```

Note that the above will **not** work properly if the model changes during runtime, specifically if rows are inserted/removed *before* any already "pressed index" (including using filter models) and if the model is sorted.

A proper implementation should use alternative ways to achieve so, for instance by setting basic bool value for a custom role in the model: in this way the "pressed" indexes will *always* be consistent, no matter what happens to the model; the fact that you don't actually use those values for the data model is irrelevant, the important thing is to keep consistency of indexes (which are not persistent by nature). Another alternative is to check/store the rows of the [QPersistentModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpersistentmodelindex.html) of each index, both for the `editorEvent()` and the `paint()` functions.